# Htaccess URL rewrite from file to directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to rewrite URL, so when a user accesses

`mysite.com/something`

I want it to show up the content of `mysite.com/something.php`, but not redirecting the user to the actual .php file.

I have many other pages like this, I want a one-for-all (wild-card) soltion, rather than setting up lines for each file.

Is there a way to do it using .htaccess?

P.S: I don't want `mysite.com/something.php` to be redirected to `mysite.com/something` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `MultiViews` option:

Ad this line on top of your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +MultiViews
```